# Using the K.function() within a custom Keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using the intermediate outputs of a larger model as the input to smaller models and I'm trying to make it one contiguous `Model`. In order to do so, I have to use the `K.function()` as a part of the model. This leads to the question:

**Is there any way to use a `K.function()` within a Keras layer?**

I created a simple custom layer using:

```
class ActivationExtraction(Layer):
    """
    Extracts all of the outputs of the input_model network and feeds it as input
    to the next layer
    """
    def __init__(self, input_model, **kwargs):
        self.input_model = input_model

        # Extracts all outputs
        outputs = [layer.output for layer in input_model.layers]
        self.output_dim = np.array(outputs).shape
        self.names = [layer.name for layer in input_model.layers]

        # Evaluation function
        self.output_function = K.function([input_model.input] + [K.learning_phase()],
                                          outputs)

        super(ActivationExtraction, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(ActivationExtraction, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return self.output_function([x, 0])

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.output_dim
```

However, when I define the model, it returns the error

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed 
values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

I don't know a workaround for evaluating the tensor at compile time (because of the input shape being dynamic). I have tried using

```
def call(self, x):
    x = K.get_session.run(x)
    return self.outputfuntion([x, 0])
```

as a long shot to try and evaluate the tensor, but I'm not sure what I would feed it (I have limited experience with tensorflow).

As a last resort, I haven't been able to find a way to evaluate a tensor on the fly in a Keras layer either.